# Can't figure out how to fix the Firebase security rules

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I started working on this app a few years ago and now I realized the database design is not very good. Unfortunately the project has become too complex for me to change anything. The app is basically an expense tracking app which allows users to add partners and track expenses together so there are some nodes I want to be only accessible by the account owner and their partners while other nodes should be accessible by everyone.

Here is the database structure :

```
 users:
  uid1:
    name:
    expenses:
    partner:
    categories:
      category1:
      category2:
      ...
  uid2:
    ...
    ...
```

As an example, lets say I want the 'name' and 'partner' to be accessible by anyone, 'expenses' to be accessible by the account owner and 'partner'

I tried the following rules:

```
{
 "rules": {
    "users":{
      "$uid":{
        "expenses":{
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid ||root.child('users').child($uid).child('partner').val() === auth.uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid || root.child('users').child($uid).child('partner').val() === auth.uid"
        },
        "categories":{
          ".read": "auth.uid === $uid ||root.child('users').child($uid).child('partner').val() === auth.uid",
            ".write": "auth.uid === $uid || root.child('users').child($uid).child('partner').val() === auth.uid"
        },"settings":{
            ".read":"auth.uid != null",
            ".write":"auth.uid != null"
        },"bankingApps":{
            ".read":"auth.uid != null",
            ".write":"auth.uid != null"
        },"loans":{
            ".read":"auth.uid != null",
            ".write":"auth.uid != null"
         },"notifications":{
            ".read":"auth.uid != null",
            ".write":"auth.uid != null"
        },"subscriptions":{
            ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
            ".write":"auth.uid === $uid"
          },
        "receipts":{
         ".read": "auth.uid === $uid ||root.child('users').child($uid).child('partner').val() === auth.uid",
         ".write": "auth.uid === $uid || root.child('users').child($uid).child('partner').val() === auth.uid"
      },"partner":{
        ".read": "auth.uid != $uid",
         ".write":"auth.uid != $uid"
      },"partnerRequest":{
        ".read": "auth.uid != $uid",
         ".write":"auth.uid != $uid"
      },"uid":{
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
         ".write":"auth.uid === $uid"
      },"theme":{
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
         ".write":"auth.uid === $uid"
      },"fullname":{
        ".read": "auth.uid != $uid",
         ".write":"auth.uid != $uid"
      },"username":{
        ".read": "auth.uid != $uid",
         ".write":"auth.uid != $uid"
      }
      }
    }
}
```

}

With these rules some of the features stop working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that is not working in the way you expect it to.